# add icon and text in JMenu in swing

Tags: java, swing, menu, jframe, awt

I am working on swings. I have to create a mainscreen consisting 10 menus. 
I have created the form by JFrame and menu by JMenu. Now that menu should contain text and image both and action performed method should be called on clicking of the menu so that action could be performed on clicking of the menu button.

Right now I'm making Jmenu with JMenuItem and icon on image icon but I want the menu with icon and text

my current code is

```
public class MenuScreen  extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

             Container cp;
             JMenuBar menuBar;

             JLabel logo;
                public MenuScreen() {
                    super("");
                    cp=this.getContentPane();
                    cp.setBackground(Color.gray);

                    menuBar= new JMenuBar();
        logo=new JLabel(im);
                cp.add(logo);
                    logo.setBounds(100,80,500,350);

            helpmenu= new JMenu(" Help  ");
        homemenu=new JMenu(" Home  ");
        fieldsmenu= new JMenu(" Fields  ");
        backmenu= new JMenu(" Back  ");
        forwardmenu= new JMenu(" Forward  ");
        panelmenu= new JMenu(" Panel  ");
        searchmenu= new JMenu(" Search  ");
        quickmenu= new JMenu(" Quick  ");
        infomenu= new JMenu(" Info  ");
        exitmenu= new JMenu(" Exit  ");
        mastermenu= new JMenu(" Master  ");
        tarrifmenu= new JMenu(" Tarrif  "); 
        contactmenu= new JMenu(" Contact  ");
        webmenu= new JMenu(" Web  ");
        wordmenu= new JMenu(" Word  ");
        legaldictionarymenu= new JMenu(" LegalDictionary  ");
        budgetmenu=new JMenu(" Budget 2012 2013  ");
        memberdetailmenu= new JMenu(" Member Details  ");


        Font f1= new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,16);

        budgetmenu.setFont(f1);
        legaldictionarymenu.setFont(f1);
        helpmenu.setFont(f1);

        JMenuItem backmenuitem= new JMenuItem(backicon);
        backmenu.add(backmenuitem);


        JMenuItem exitmenuitem= new JMenuItem(exiticon);
        exitmenu.add(exitmenuitem);

        menuBar.add(helpmenu);
        menuBar.add(homemenu);
        menuBar.add(fieldsmenu);
        menuBar.add(backmenu);
        menuBar.add(forwardmenu);
        menuBar.add(panelmenu);
        menuBar.add(searchmenu);
        menuBar.add(quickmenu);
        menuBar.add(infomenu);
        menuBar.add(exitmenu);
        menuBar.add(mastermenu);
        menuBar.add(tarrifmenu);
        menuBar.add(contactmenu);
        menuBar.add(webmenu);
        menuBar.add(wordmenu);
        menuBar.add(legaldictionarymenu);
        menuBar.add(budgetmenu);
        menuBar.add(memberdetailmenu);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    /*
     Adding Listeners to the menus where required 

     */
            searchmenu.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"clicked");
          if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Search"))
          {

           SearchForm frm=new SearchForm();
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
          frm.setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
          frm.setVisible(true);


          }           

    }

   public static void main(String args[])
{

       MenuScreen frm= new MenuScreen();

       Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
       frm.setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
       frm.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

please help me.

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.   Code in questions is much more useful if it is readable.  With the way that code is indented, I could read my dog's breakfast more easily.

Comment: Some tips 1) If the question is 'how to add icon and text to menu item?' add code that contains one menu with one menu item rather than 10 menus and over 100 lines of code. 2) `logo.setBounds(100,80,500,350);`  Don't do that, it will cause problems later.  Instead use layouts (with padding & borders).

Answer (score 11):

Use the constructor `JMenuItem(String text, Icon icon)` 

If you want JMenu with Icon and Text do

```
helpmenu= new JMenu(" Help  ");
helpmenu.setIcon(..);
```

Comment: thanks it is displaying the icon before the text but i want text under the icon means icon above and text under icon and click event should be performed with Jmenu

Comment: @ADESHRAJPUT please read the chapter on how-to use JMenu/Items in the tutorial referenced in the swing-tag wiki - mere api questions are boring for the helpers and don't help you overly much ... at the end of the day, you'll have to learn the api you are using and that ultimately can only be done by reading it :-)

Answer (score 3):

**-** For the `JMenuItem` use `JMenuItem((String text, Icon icon)` **constructor**,

**-** And for `JMenu` try using the **constructor** which takes String as an Argument `JMenu(String s)`, and **method** `setIcon()`

**For setting the special key options on the MenuItems use** `setAccelerator()`

**Eg:**

`myItem.setAccelerator(
         KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));`

Answer (score 2):

Set the icon and text in your `Action` which you place on the menu (using the key-value pair mechanism). The keys are defined in the `Action` interface.

The [class javadoc of the `Action` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) also contains a nice overview table of the available keys and what they affect.